# How to retrieve string data from many to many form field in django

Tags: python, django, while-loop, django-views, django-forms

I'm programming using django, and I encountered the following issue. This might be a little complicated, but I would like to make the following while loop work in a form_valid function in my view. First of all, here is the loop:

```
        i = 0
        while i <= days:
            days_added = i
            current_end = class_start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days_added)
            str_current_end = str(current_end)
            current_end_day = calendar.day_name[datetime.datetime.strptime(str(current_end), '%Y-%m-%d').weekday()]
            if current_end_day == 'Saturday' or current_end_day == 'Sunday':
                days = days + 1
            elif str_current_end == '2021-04-09' or str_current_end == '2021-04-13':
                days = days + 1
            elif all_weekdays[0] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[1] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[2] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[3] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[4] != current_end_day:
                days = days + 1
            i += 1
```

There are more to the code in the form_valid function to actually make this while loop work, but my problem is only with the last elif statement that contains `all_weekdays`. You see, I defined `all weekdays` as `all_weekdays = form.instance.weekday.all()` before I started the while loop. Here, `weekday` is a "many to many field" in the form submitted by the user. Basically, the user could select multiple options from Monday to Friday, which will be stored in the `weekday`. Also, `current_end_day` is just a value that can be between Sunday to Saturday (any day of the week). Basically, I want the last elif statement to check if one of the days in the `weekday` is not  equal to the `current_end_day`. If it is not equal, then I want to run the math:

```
days = days + 1
```

Since there are only 5 options for `weekdays`(Monday to Friday), I just listed out `all_weekdays[0]` to `all_weekdays[4]`, and check if any of the values is not equal to `current_end_day`. However, when I submit the form in my browser, the page just keeps loading and doesn't do anything. I hope you guys could help me with this issue, and comment me if you need other informations. Thanks a lot.

This is some additional information:
When I `print(current_end_day)` I get:

```
Wednesday
```

When I `print(all_weekdays)` I get:

```
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Tuesday>, <Weekday: Wednesday>, <Weekday: Thursday>]>
```

Here is the model Weekday:

```
class Weekday(models.Model):
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Input weekday')

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.weekday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write this statement:

```
all_weekdays[0] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[1] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[2] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[3] != current_end_day or all_weekdays[4] != current_end_day
```

What do you suppose is the truth value of this statement? Let's say that all_weekdays is a list from Monday to Friday and `current_end_day` is Wednesday. This becomes:

```
"Monday" != "Wednesday" or "Tuesday" != "Wednesday" or ...
```

Notice the problem yet? Well `current_end_day` is not Monday so you can rewrite the statement as:

```
True or "Tuesday" != "Wednesday" or ...
```

And what is the truth value of `True or statement`? It is `True` of course so you are going into an infinite loop.

Also `current_end_day` is simply a string while `all_weekdays` is a QuerySet of `Weekday` objects hence your comparison would always fail. You should firsty get the corresponding `Weekday` object and use that to compare or as your own comment shows filter on the QuerySet `all_weekdays` to check if `current_end_day` exists in it:

```
elif not all_weekdays.filter(weekday=current_end_day).exists():
    days = days + 1
```

Comment: @JohnSong check my edit. Although your code looks very problematic since the `Weekday` can have multiple of the same entries why is the field `weekday` not unique? Also ensure that even `Sunday` and `Saturday` which you might not have as entries in the database also are present in this table.

Comment: How about this code? `elif not all_weekdays.filter(Weekday=current_end_day).exists():` and then `days = days + 1`?

Comment: @JohnSong great catch! Updated my answer to reflect the same (yes that would work, infact better than my suggestion). :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I'm still not getting the result I want in the overall logic. If I have another issue, can I stay in contact with you through chat or this comment section?

Comment: @JohnSong if the question is different from this current one better post a different question. Otherwise be free to comment here for any clarification. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways. The overall logic works btw. One last question just out of curiosity. Is `all_weekdays` a list, array, or queryset with objects? This is because I would like to know when I can apply the filter().

Comment: @JohnSong `all_weekdays` is a queryset. Likely you got this from the `cleaned_data`? The form turns all inputs into what they ideally should be so a field for an m2m would be cleaned and turned into a queryset, a foreign key is turned into the related object, etc.. (Do delete the comments from above which are unneeded, the comments are getting quite bulky)